How to import NgModule into Standalone Angular17 project
I was unable to import NgModule into my standalone project
i tried importing NgModule , but i got error that i cannot import NgModule or directives or pipes directly. I want code for my angular app where i should be able to use file viewer, file uploader, pomodoro timer, and many which definetly need Ng Module which is not getting imported into my project. Please do let me know the answer as fast as possible.
My email Id is btarun042@gmail.com,mobile number 7981754448
i tried importing NgModule , but i got error that i cannot import NgModule or directives or pipes directly. I want code for my angular app where i should be able to use file viewer, file uploader, pomodoro timer, and many which definetly need Ng Module which is not getting imported into my project. Please do let me know the answer as fast as possible.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

In the stand-alone components, we have imports : [] array in the component decorator, we can use any modules in the array like
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

you can install any third party package and used in the imports array.

I want ImageUploadComponent , FileUploadServuce which is not coming.
I m getting CommonModule and FormsModule.I also wang NgModule

you want to import another component. Am I right?
you can import other stand-alone components into standalone components. But other components must have standalone property. then you should make others standalone components, then you can import with no errors.
